# How does minus integer work in Date?

Tags: javascript

How does javascript Date interpret the milisecond integers?

```
var d = new Date(-1724115600000); //this gives me a date in the past, which I want
console.log(d);

var d = new Date(1724115600000); 
console.log(d);
```

(we had a bug where the - sign was not getting through. But I dont understand the significance of the -)

Comment: The 2nd one [gives me a date in the future](http://imgur.com/u8daUDR) - are you sure it's in the past for you?

Comment: Are you from the future?

Comment: The second one is `Date {Mon Aug 19 2024 20:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)}` - that's in *my* future at least.

Comment: As for how it interprets them, [it's the milliseconds since midnight, 1st Jan, 1970](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) - if you're getting something other than May 15 1915 and Aug 20 2024 (ish), then there's something wrong with your javascript implementation...

Comment: "Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)." a very good, I missed that.

Comment: No I am not from the future. If I was then I certainly hope I'm still not struggling with JS bugs on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: James can you Post your answer so I can mark it as the answer. thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` object constructor can take a [variety of inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters), but when called in this fashion it's using the integer value one:

> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

Negative values will give dates before the Unix Epoch, positive values are dates after the Epoch.

Answer (score 2):

0 would be 1. January 1970. The delta is given as an unsigned number representing milliseconds. If you want dates before that you need to use negative values in milliseconds.

The negative number you provided will give a number in the past, the other one in the future:

> Date 1915-05-14T23:00:00.000Z
>   Date 2024-08-20T01:00:00.000Z

If you got one in the past with the second number it may have been missing the last digit when your tried. In that case it would give:

> Date 1975-06-19T12:06:00.000Z

```js
var d = new Date(-1724115600000); //this gives me a date in the past, which I want
document.write(d + "<br>");

var d = new Date(1724115600000); //This gives me a date in the past too. 
document.write(d + "<br>");

var d = new Date(172411560000); //missing last digit
document.write(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//negative sign give you the date before 1970. in your example

var d = new Date(-1425223942000);// this gives date in the past
        document.write(d)  //Sun Nov 02 1924 03:27:38 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

document.write('<br/>')
var d = new Date(1425223942000); //This gives date in th  future. 
document.write(d); // Sun Mar 01 2015 10:32:22 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

//Unfortunately i cannot post the screenshots yet
```